# C - How to manipulate typedef structure pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

```
typedef struct
{
int id;
char*  first;
char* last;
}* person;

person* people;
```

Hi.
How can I use this above, all set globally, to fill people with different "person"s? I am having issues wrapping my head regarding the typedef struct pointer.
I am aware pointers are like arrays, but I'm having issues getting this all together...

I would like to keep the above code as is as well.

Edit 1: char first should be char* first.

Comment: If you're "aware that pointers are like arrays", it would be best to empty your mind, throw away your book and start over with a better one.

Comment: I personally don't like hiding the pointer type inside the `typedef` like that.  In your case, it also appears to be wrong.  Can you change those definitions at all?

Comment: Pointers and arrays while related... are not the same thing.

Comment: When you say "all set globally" do you mean that you want a massive code block that will initialize a big block of these to a set of known values. As in you don't want to add to the list of people during runtime, but set it up completely before?

Comment: Well the code above is global. I will have functions such ass "addPerson()", etc. Sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create an array of structures of type `person` using something like following:

```
people = malloc (num_person * sizeof(person));
for (i = 0; i < num_person; i++) {
     people[i]->first = malloc (size * sizeof(char));
     people[i]->last = malloc (size * sizeof(char));
}
```

Following this, you could fill up each `people struct` with different parameters.

Comment: I don't think this answer is right, given the OP's definitions of `person` and `people`.

Comment: That was my error. It was meant to be a char*. Testing the above code now.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes, I just assumed that it was a typo in the question.

Comment: `sizeof(person)` is still going to be the size of a pointer, not the size of a structure, though.  Anyway, since `person` is a pointer type, I think there needs to be some more allocation here.

Comment: @CarlNorum, yes you are right, had not noticed that!.. actually then people becomes a double pointer.. not sure of the motive here.

Comment: Going based on the double pointer, how would malloc'ing for example, first go?

Answer (score 2):

Ugly as sin. You really should redefine person to not be a pointer. Also don't use anonymous structs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int id;
    char*  first;
    char* last;
}* person;

person* people = (person[]){
    (person)&(struct {int id;char*  first;char* last;}){0,"me","foo"},
    (person)&(struct {int id;char*  first;char* last;}){0,"you","foo"},
    NULL
};

int main(void) {
    while(*people) {
        printf("%s %s\n", (*people)->first, (*people)->last);
        people++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Don't bother with typedefs for structs**. It's much clearer if you use structs with tags and then do your thing:

```
struct PERSON {
    int id;
    char *first;
    char *last;
};

struct PERSON *people;  /* people is a pointer to a struct PERSON. */

/* Allocate array of 42 struct PERSONS. */
people = malloc (42 * sizeof *people);

/* Now use people[0] to people[41]. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Typedefs that hide the real type are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the double indirection, I guess something like:

```
people = malloc(sizeof(person));
*people = malloc(SOME_NUMBER * sizeof(**people));
```

Will allocate what you need.  You'd get an individual person structure out like:

```
(*people)[INDEX]
```

When using a particular person structure, you'll need to allocate memory for the `first` and `last` strings as well:

```
(*people)[INDEX].first = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
(*people)[INDEX].last = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
```

But simply removing the crazy double indirection will really clean things up and make everything a lot easier to use and understand:

```
people = malloc(SOME_NUMBER * sizeof(person));
people[INDEX].first = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
people[INDEX].last = malloc(STRING_SIZE);
```

Comment: I think the OP is not aware of the double pointer implied. (that being that the typedef embeds one and then the allocation creates another one). Might want to explain that a little more.

Comment: Thanks for replies. @Carl, if you can explain a tad more, I would highly appreciate it! Basically double vs single.

Comment: @AbhishekJoshi - your `typedef` has a `*` in it, which means the type you're creating is a pointer type.  Then you declared a global variable of type `person *`, but since `person` is already a pointer type, you end up with a global variable that is a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-your-structure.  Just delete the `*` on line 6 of your example to clean things up.